# Ist der Gebrauch von „zeitgleich“ als Synonym für „gleichzeitig“ neueren Ursprungs?

Tags: word-choice, usage

Im Laufe der letzten Jahre fällt mir immer häufiger auf, dass in den Nachrichten statt *gleichzeitig* das Wort *zeitgleich* verwendet wird, wie z. B.

> Dort wurden mit 250 Polizisten zeitgleich Razzien in 20 Städten durchgeführt.

Vermutlich bin ich durch den [Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,307443,00.html) sensibilisiert, der wie auch das [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zeitgleich) sagt, dass *zeitgleich* eigentlich eine gleiche Zeitdauer und nicht eine Gleichzeitigkeit beschreibt. (In dieser Bedeutung hat das Wort nur wenige Anwendungsmöglichkeiten, vor allem bei Weltmeisterschaften in der Leichtathletik.)

Meine Frage ist nun *nicht*, ob der synonyme Gebrauch von *zeitgleich* und *gleichzeitig* akzeptabel ist, sondern *seit wann* er zu beobachten ist. Stimmt mein Eindruck, dass es eine neueres Phänomen ist (nach dem Jahr 2000 entstanden), oder gibt es diese Verwirrung schon länger, mir ist sie aber früher nie aufgefallen?

Comment: Erstmal muss man trotzdem klären, ob die Zwiebelfisch-These so stimmt. Sie klingt freilich logisch, bewiesen ist sie dadurch nicht. Die Frage ist also, ob es überhaupt eine *Verwirrung* ist.

Comment: @Debilski: Die Frage, ob die These so stimmt, habe ich bewusst ausgeklammert. Meine Verwirrung ist eher, warum überhaupt "zeitgleich" statt "gleichzeitig" gesagt wird.

Comment: Ich würde sagen dass das "zeitgleich", ob die geeignete Vokabel oder nicht, falsch ist. Zeitgleich mit 250 Polizisten? Was für ein Blödsinn! In 20 Städten zeitgleich (oder gleichzeitig) muss es heißen.

Comment: @userunknown: Nur, wenn man darauf besteht, das "zeitgleich" mit dem "mit" von den "mit 250 Polizisten" in Zusammenhang zu bringen, ansonsten ist der Satz durchaus richtig. "Wir kommen alle zeitgleich/gleichzeitig mit dem Fahrrad an." hat schließlich auch nicht zwangsläufig die Hauptaussage, dass wir zur selben Zeit wie unsere Fahrräder ankommen, sondern dass alle Mitglieder der Gruppe "wir" zur selben Zeit ankommen, nebenbei bemerkt per Fahrrad. Du hast aber Recht damit, dass es rein satzbautechnisch gesehen mehrdeutig ist und man sich die gemeinte Aussage über den Kontext erschließen muss.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ich würde sagen, dass doch, also dass die Aussage wäre, dass Ihr alle gleichzeitig mit euren Rädern ankommt, und nicht etwa radfahrend gleichzeitig ankommt, zum Beispiel weil Ihr Bike'n'Ride bei der Bahn macht, oder Trickradfahrer seid, die oft nach euren Rädern und mit Platzwunden ankommen. Vielleicht helfen Kommas: "Wir kommen zeitgleich, mit den Rädern, an."

Answer (score 10):

Der [Google Ngram Viewer zeigt für beide Wörter im Vergleich von 1945 bis 2008](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zeitgleich%2Cgleichzeitig&year_start=1945&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) folgende Grafik:

[image: zeitgleich,gleichzeitig chart]

Man sieht deutlich, dass das Wort *"zeitgleich"* ab den 1960er Jahren häufiger als früher verwendet wird, und die Häufigkeit ab den 1980ern exponentiell gestiegen ist. Meine These ist, dass die Sportberichterstattung dazu beigetragen hat.

[image: zeitgleich chart]

Comment: Hui, Fakten statt Bauchgefühl. Impressive. ^^

Comment: Leider erkennt man aus Deiner Antwort noch nicht, _wie_ "zeitgleich" ab 1980 vermehrt verwendet wurde, aber Fakten statt Bauchgefühl gefällt mir sehr gut - vielen Dank für die erhellende Statistik! (Ich könnte jetzt die These aufstellen, dass in den 80ern die Verwendung noch mehr "gleiche Zeitdauer" war und es dann später auch vermehrt anderweitig verwendet wurde ...)

Comment: @Hendrik ja, da stimme ich dir zu. Der Begriff selbst wird öfter verwendet. Ich glaube aber, dass einfach das "Öfter-Hören" bei vielen auch dazu geführt hat, es falsch zu verwenden.

Comment: Ich meinte in der Tat den "Öfter-Hören-Effekt". Nur wie überprüft man das? `:-)`

Comment: Der exponentielle Anstieg beginnt nicht 1980. Auch der schwache Anstieg zu Beginn einer exponentiellen Entwicklung ist exponentiell. :)

Comment: Hier von exponentiell zu sprechen halte ich für fragwürdig. Die Kurve flacht auch sehr schnell wieder ab.

Answer (score 7):

[Grimms Wörterbuch](http://germazope.uni-trier.de/Projekte/WBB2009/DWB/wbgui_py?lemid=GZ03901&prefix=z&mainmode=) hat nicht viel dazu zu sagen, nennt aber *gleichzeitig* als einzige Bedeutung und nicht etwa *von gleicher Dauer* und bringt dazu u. a. einen Beleg aus dem Jahr 1663.

(**Edit-Einschub**: Habe diesen ersten Beleg gerade geprüft: Schottelius, *Ausführliche Arbeit Von der Teutschen HaubtSprache*, [Faksimile](http://diglib.hab.de/drucke/ko-306/start.htm?image=00519). Interessanterweise übersetzt dieser mit *coaevus*, was laut Online-Latein-Wörterbüchern in erster Linie *von gleichem Alter* bedeutet… Keine Ahnung, was das jetzt für die Interpretation des grimmschen Wörterbuchs heißt. Den Rest will ich aber nicht überprüfen.)

Irgendwie kann ich mir andererseits aber auch vorstellen, dass der Bedarf, etwas im wörtlichen  Sinne als ‚zeitgleich‘, also *von gleicher Dauer* zu bezeichnen, eigentlich nie besonders groß gewesen sein kann. Wann will man so etwas überhaupt so dringlich ausdrücken, dass man das Wort dafür braucht? Da sind Ereignisse *zum gleichen Zeitpunkt* doch irgendwie interessanter.

**Zusatz-Statistik**

[Spiegel-Archiv 60er Jahre](http://www.spiegel.de/suche/index.html?suchbegriff=zeitgleich&suchzeitraum=1970&toDate=31.12.1969): Fundstellen **4**. Bedeutungen: *gleicher Zeitpunkt* (2), *gleichlang* (2, beide Sport)
[Spiegel-Archiv 70er Jahre](http://www.spiegel.de/suche/index.html?suchbegriff=zeitgleich&fromDate=01.01.1970&toDate=31.12.1979): Fundstellen **14**. Bedeutungen: *gleicher Zeitpunkt* (12), *gleichlang* (0)

Natürlich müsste man zur Einschätzung wissen, wie vollständig *der Spiegel* alte Ausgaben digitalisiert hat.

Comment: Sehr interessant! Dass die Grimms "zeitgleich" schon in dieser Bedeutung erwähnen, überzeugt mich davon, dass es keine neue _Erfindung_ ist. Es bleibt die Frage nach der _Verbreitung_ (in der Bedeutung "gleichzeitig).

Comment: (Ich hatte ja schon in meiner Frage geschrieben, dass die Bedeutung _von gleicher Dauer_ nur wenige Anwendungsmöglichkeiten hat.)

Comment: (Oh, hoppla. Das mit der schlechten Anwendbarkeit hatte ich zwar gelesen, aber irgendwie beim Tippen wieder vergessen und plötzlich  als eigenen Gedanken interpretiert.)

Comment: (Das passiert mir auch manchmal.)

Comment: hmh, schöne Recherche. :) virtuelle +2 von mir. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Vom Gefühl her würde ich es genau in die Zeit verorten, in der man angefangen hat das temporale "in", wie zum Beispiel "In 2000 fiel ein Sack Reis in China um.", aus dem Englischen zu importieren. Wird so 1995~2000 gewesen sein.

Comment: @ladybug: Nur leider Fakten, die nicht die Frage beantworten.